# Odd Javascript alert output

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, alert

I have an odd problem. I'm trying to use Javascript to fetch me some values from a multidimensional array, and it's giving me some weird output.

Here is my code:

```
foo = [['3','4'],['5','6']];

for (bar in foo) {

    baz = bar[0];
    alert(baz);

    qux = bar[1];
    alert(qux);

}
```

Here is the output of the above:

```
// These are all alerts, by the way
0,undefined,1,undefined,$,f,$,c,e,a,c,l,c,l,i,i,n,a,s,l,i,c,o,a,p,g,e,g,e,i,n,c,o,e,r,e,m,f,l,p,i,h,e,r,g
```

Can somebody tell me what is happening?

Here is a jsFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Jey6w/

**Edit:**

Here is another jsFiddle, with another layer of "Inception": http://jsfiddle.net/8vyGq/

The output:

```
// Again, these are all alerts, and * signifies undefined
0**1**$ff$ceaacllcllinnassliicooappgeegeeinncooerremmfllpiiheergg
```

Comment: Use `console.log` and the developer console or Firebug Lite. `Array.prototype.toString` turns the array into a csv list of the strings of each item in the array. `alert` implicitly call's `toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think it's due to the fact that `bar` is returning a reference to a property within an object. Changing your selectors to `foo[bar][0]` works a treat.

```
foo = [['3','4'],['5','6']];

for (bar in foo) {
    alert(foo[bar][0]);
    alert(foo[bar][1]);
}​
```

In cases where your object is simply a multi-dimensional array, I would sway array from using the `for in` statement, as it can select unwanted properties. I would stick to the good old fashioned `for(start, stop, increment)`

```
foo = [['3','4'],['5','6']];

for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    alert(foo[i][0]);
    alert(foo[i][1]);
}​
```

### Update - jQuery

As there has been mention of jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method I thought I'd also post an example of how it could be utilised. The jQuery's each method passes 2 optional parameters, `indexInArray`, and `valueOfElement`. Additionally, the jQuery documentation also states that

> The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but
>   Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is
>   a simple string or number value

With this in mind, we could achieve the same results as previous example, using the following jQuery ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/Jey6w/1/)):

```
var foo = [['3','4'],['5','6']];

$.each(foo, function() {
    // 'this' is the context of the current item within the array
    alert(this[0]);
    alert(this[1]);
}​)​
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use this approach. It's cleanest and doesn't require the use of a library. I'm still a little disconcerted as to why the original approach wouldn't work. 0_o

Comment: To anyone coming after, see @Pointy's answer for the reason why the weird output is happening.

Answer (score 6):

The JavaScript `for ... in` loop gives you the **names** of the object properties, not the values.

Don't use `for ... in` for real arrays. Use a numeric index or `.forEach()`.

The reason you're getting your output is complicated and uninteresting, since you just shouldn't do that, but here's a start. The property names will be coerced to strings by the `for ... in`.  Thus, on the first iteration, "bar" is the string "0", so `("0")[0]` is just "0", and `("0")[1]` is `undefined` because "bar" is a single-character string.

After that, your `for ... in` loop staggers into some other properties inherited from somewhere; perhaps you're using Prototype or something. The loop then alerts the first two characters of the names of all those other properties.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why that's happening.

I'm actually using jQuery, and I could be mistaken, but I don't believe jQuery's .each() can be used for non-DOM-related array traversal.

Comment: @InterfaceGuy the `$.each()` utility can, and also modern browsers have a `.forEach()` and you can find drop-in "shims" for older browsers.